# Java 15, Nashorn 15.3: Can't access to java object public methods or properties

Tags: java, nashorn

This is my example:

```java
package mypkg;
import javax.script.*;
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Start");
    Main app = new Main();
    app.test();
  }

  public void test() throws Exception {
    ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
        engine.put("manager", new JsObjTest());
        engine.put("clazz", JsObjTest.class);
        engine.eval("load('nashorn:mozilla_compat.js');");
        engine.eval("print(manager.getVal());");
  }
}

class JsObjTest {
  public String getVal() {
    return "Demo";
  }
}
```

I've got an error, when I call public method:

```
java -cp .:nashorn-core-15.3.jar:asm-7.3.1.jar:asm-util-7.3.1.jar mypkg.Main
Start
Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: manager.getVal is not a function in <eval> at line number 1
    at org.openjdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:463)
```

What I must to do, to resolve this problem? Thanks

Comment: It’s surprising that you got so far with JDK 15, as the Nashorn engine has been removed in this version. In earlier Java versions, you have to declare `class JsObjTest` as `public` to make your code work. But you’re still riding a dead horse…

Comment: Yes, In JDK 15 nashorn was removed from JDK, but It available in standalone packages. I included it into classpath: 
```bash
java -cp .:nashorn-core-15.3.jar:asm-7.3.1.jar:asm-util-7.3.1.jar...
```

Comment: Holger, you are was right. It's works, if move JsObjTest class into separate file as public